# Exactly the same Xhtml displays differently depeneding on hostname

Tags: asp.net, iis, xhtml

I have a web page.

When I view it under localhost it looks ok e.g. http://localhost/MySite/ is fine

When I view it using the specific name of my machine one of the pages renders incorrectly e.g. http://MyMachineName/MySite/

However the Xhtml is identical. This makes no sense to me.

(IIS 5/ASP.NET 3.5/XHTML Transitional)

Comment: Can you give us a bit more detail on HOW it's rendering differently?

Comment: It was a menu composed of list items breaking onto two lines. It was actually because in localhost compatibility mode was set and in the my maachine name compatibility mode wasn't. So it was a simple IE7 vs Ie8 problem as opposed to something more sinister. I am duly embarassed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments above.

Make sure compatibility mode is set for both localhost and the machine name.

(this answer is just for others who may come across this question. The OP solved this themselves)